# maven failsafe with azure pipeline gives error

Tags: azure, maven, azure-devops, maven-failsafe-plugin

I have created an api test project using cucumber. When I run project using Intellij with command  `mvn clean verify -P acceptanceTests` it runs fine. But when I am running it in azure pipeline I am receiving this error

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-failsafe-plugin:3.0.0-M5:verify (verify) on project com.test: There are test failures.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please refer to /home/vsts/work/1/s/target/failsafe-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date].dump, [date]-jvmRun[N].dump and [date].dumpstream.
[ERROR] org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called?
[ERROR] Command was /bin/sh -c cd /home/vsts/work/1/s && /usr/lib/jvm/adoptopenjdk-11-hotspot-amd64/bin/java -javaagent:/home/vsts/.m2/repository/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/1.9.1/aspectjweaver-1.9.1.jar @/home/vsts/work/1/s/target/surefire/surefireargs12930524259006620681 /home/vsts/work/1/s/target/surefire 2021-03-24T20-45-21_548-jvmRun1 surefire2852794554623212644tmp surefire_01307379121946876339tmp
[ERROR] Error occurred in starting fork, check output in log
```

Here is pipeline yml

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
  
- task: JavaToolInstaller@0
  inputs:
      versionSpec: '11'
      jdkArchitectureOption: 'x64'
      jdkSourceOption: 'PreInstalled'

- task: Maven@3
  inputs:
    mavenPomFile: 'pom.xml'
    mavenOptions: '-Xmx3072m'
    #javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
    #jdkVersionOption: '1.11'
    jdkArchitectureOption: 'x64'
    publishJUnitResults: true
    testResultsFiles: '**/failsafe-reports/*.dump'
    goals: 'clean verify -P acceptanceTests -e '
```

I tried to search but couldnt find any pointers. How can I debug this? I was trying to see the `.dump` file through `'**/failsafe-reports/*.dump'` above but I am not sure how to or if it is the right way

Comment: Hi, Which agent are you using? Hosted agent or self-hosted agent? Since it runs successfully locally, you could run the pipeline again with self-hosted agent and then kindly share the result here. In addition, according to the error message, please check your pom.xml file and check the filed maven-failsafe-plugin

Comment: It looks like you have test failures as shown in the error message `There are test failures.`... please check that first...

Comment: Pls change the goals to `clean verify -P acceptanceTests -e -X` and enable debug logs via "-X". Attach the log. We have to see it. The best idea is to have a separate project on GitHub where we can reproduce this issue and investigate. Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some troubleshooting found that removing unwanted/unused snippet from `pom.xml` helped resolve above error. The unused snippet was not causing any issue in local but was causing the above error in azure.Also ,  it seems that error was not because of issue in actual tests. This was the snippet causing the error

```
<properties>
 <property>
 <name>listener</name>
 <value>io.qameta.allure.junit5.AllureJunit5</value>
 </property>
 </properties>
 <argLine>
 -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar"
 </argLine>
 <systemProperties>
 <property>
 <name>allure.results.directory</name>
 <value>${project.basedir}/allure-results</value>
 </property>
 <property>
 <name>junit.jupiter.extensions.autodetection.enabled</name>
 <value>true</value>
 </property>
 </systemProperties>
 <reportFormat>plain</reportFormat>
```

Comment: Can you remove one by one? I want to see the impact to the plugin. Since I am a developer of Surefire and Failsafe plugin, I am interested.

Comment: I think its because of this `<argLine>                      -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar"
                    </argLine>`

Comment: You'r right, we need to see the dump files. It looks like JVM related issue which typically appears in the dump files. Pls add a Shell script to your Travis build, iterate over these dump files and print their content on the console. We are doing similar tasks, see https://github.com/apache/maven-surefire/blob/master/.travis.yml and https://github.com/apache/maven-surefire/blob/master/.travis.sh

Comment: Hi @user1207289, Thanks for the sharing, you could [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) , it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread. Thanks. Have a nice day. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you touched the same [bug](https://github.com/apache/maven-surefire/pull/343) we are currently fixing and which is part of Jira issue **SUREFIRE-1881**.